# How to find out whether a conditional value falls within a range of values in another table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm stuck with a problem in Excel where I want to find out whether a certain value in one table falls within a range of values in another table. In short, I want to find out whether an action from person x is being followed up on within 90 days after the initial date. Table 1 displays the persons and their initial dates, while table 2 shows the persons and their actual date.

[Link to the 2 tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7XDO.png)

I already tried to built a formula with VLOOKUP, but the problem I encountered with this is that it only looks at the first date (e.g. id_number 5999 and 01/01/2014) instead of both or more dates (in reality I could have 5 or more dates that need to be looked at). The formula I used so far is: `=VLOOKUP(A4,I:J,2,0)-C4`. After this I checked whether it falls within 90 days with this formula `=IF(AND(D4<90,D4>=0),1,0)`.

The id_number makes it hard for me as the formula should consider this as a condition when looking in the other table.

Comment: You're going to have to edit your question with an example of the code you tried, and a better explanation of the result received with what you have tried and an explanation of what you are expecting, so we can help you. Here is a link that's hopefully going to help you with that and also hopefully help you in the future, so you don't lose time editing and reading comments like mine. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've edited it and hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to return largest follow-up date or all dates?

**1. Largest date:**
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER($H$4:$H$8,$G$4:$G$8=A4),,-1),1)

**2. All dates:**
=TEXTJOIN(" | ",TRUE,TEXT(SORT(FILTER($H$4:$H$8,$G$4:$G$8=A4)),"dd/mm/yyyy"))

[Sample solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcF6a.png)

**EDIT:**
Based on edited inquiry I would go with something like this:

=IF(SUM(IF(SORT(FILTER($H$4:$H$5,$G$4:$G$5=A4))-B4<90,1,0))>0,TRUE,FALSE)

[New solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH1yl.png)

Comment: Thank you for the formulas. Unfortunately, it does not quite answer my question. I'm seeking to find out whether the follow-up date is within 90 days after the inital date (so, essentially a Boolean) which is not possible with the formulas you provided if I'm correct. I have edited my initial question to make it hopefully clearer.

Comment: Please see the edited part in my response :)